# Prove that for $n\in N^*$ and $a,x \geq 0$ : $(a+x)^{n+1} \geq \frac{(n+1)^{n+1}}{n^n}a^nx$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, inequality

> Prove that for $n\in N^*$ and $a,x \geq 0$ : $(a+x)^{n+1} \geq \frac{(n+1)^{n+1}}{n^n}a^nx$

**My proof :**

$$(a+x)^{n+1} = \bigg(n\frac{a}{n} + x\bigg)^{n+1} = \bigg( \frac{a}{n} + \frac{a}{n} + \dots +\frac{a}{n} +x \bigg)^{n+1} $$

$$\geq$$

$$\bigg[ (n+1)\bigg(\frac{a}{n}\cdot\frac{a}{n}\cdot \dots \cdot \frac{a}{n}\cdot x\bigg)^{\frac{1}{n+1}} \bigg]^{n+1}$$

$$= $$

$$\bigg\{ (n+1) \bigg[ \bigg(\frac{a}{n}\bigg)^nx\bigg]^{\frac{1}{n+1}} \bigg\}^{n+1}$$

$$=$$

$$\frac{(n+1)^{n+1}}{n^n}a^nx$$

Wanted to ask if my approach seems correct and smooth enough, or if there's a better/easier way to prove it.

Comment: I think you are right.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Thanks for the reply !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the AM-GM inequality, then
$$\frac{\frac{a}{n}+\frac{a}{n}+...+\frac{a}{n}+x}{n+1}\geq \sqrt[n+1]{\left(\frac{a}{n}\right)^n\cdot x}$$

Comment: Yeah, true, more straight forward ! Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

A  suggestive proof is the following: 
$$(a+x)^{n+1} \geq \frac{(n+1)^{n+1}}{n^n}a^nx\iff 1\ge\frac{Ax}{(a+x)^{n+1}}$$ where $A=\dfrac{(n+1)^{n+1}a^n}{n^n}$.

For each $(n,a)\in\mathbb N^*\text{ x }\mathbb R_+$ fixed define the function
$$f_{n,a}(x)=\frac{Ax}{(a+x)^{n+1}}\Rightarrow f'(x)=\frac{A(a-nx)}{(a+x)^{n+2}}$$ It follows $f$ has a maximum at $x=\dfrac an$ and $$f_{n,a}(\frac an)=\dfrac{(n+1)^{n+1}a^n}{n^n}\cdot\frac{\dfrac an}{(a+\dfrac an)^{n+1}}=1$$ Thus for all of our $n,a$ one has $$1\ge\frac{Ax}{(a+x)^{n+1}}$$ which is the (equivalent) proposed inequality.

Comment: Yep, good too. My proof is correct all in all as well, right ?